# Does TestDriven.NET work with VS Express?

Tags: testdriven.net

Does TestDriven.NET work with VS Express?

EDIT:
Yeah, I just installed it and noticed that it wasn't working. It looks like a really cool program.

Comment: it was an infamous debate when the author was made to remove that support.

http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2007/05/31/microsoft-vs-testdriven-net-31-may-2007.aspx

http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/2007/06/04/OnePerspectiveOnMicrosoftVsTestDrivenNET.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [release notes](http://www.testdriven.net/downloads/ReleaseNotes.html) for TestDriven.NET, support for the Express editions of Visual Studio was removed in 2.8 (2.08).

Answer (score 4):

I have a vague recollection of the author of TestDriven getting into all sorts of bother with Microsoft threatening to revoke his MVP status unless he modified it to only work with the non-free versions of VS.

See [here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2007/06/05/microsoft_mvp_threats/) for all the gory details.

The front page states that it "supports all versions of Microsoft Visual Studio" but the release notes indicate otherwise:

`"Jamie Cansdale and Microsoft Corporation have agreed to concentrate on working together on future releases of TestDriven.Net for Microsoft's officially extensible editions of Visual Studio, as opposed to spending time litigating their differences."`

Officially extensible version don't include the free ones, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

[Doesn't look like it](http://testdriven.net/overview.aspx) (look in the bottom right)

I seem to remember Microsoft insisting that it not work on the Express versions, and some blog posts around that.

Comment: Yeah, I just installed it and noticed, it wasn't working.  Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Small note: The personal edition of TestDriven.Net 3.9 does indeed work with VS 2015 Community Edition.